# XML Cross Apply Assist - Secondary level and multiple rows

Tags: sql, xml, apply

I was wondering if someone could assist me with some XML work I am doing on SQL, frustratingly theyve asked for further information and struggling.

Attached is the XML:

```html
<pagedata>
  <BinderSections REPEATINGTYPE="PageList">
    <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="1">
       <Compliance>
        <EstPolicyCount REPEATINGTYPE="PropertyGroup">
          <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="Total12">30</rowdata>
          <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="NonSME">30</rowdata>
        </EstPolicyCount>
      </Compliance>
    </rowdata>
  </BinderSections>
</pagedata>
```

I need to use in an XML query, I can get most of it using the following SQL:

```sql
DECLARE @id INT 
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @id = 1

WHILE (@id <= 1)
BEGIN

SET @SQL = '
SELECT
  t.TransID
  --BinderSection.value(N''(rowdata[@REPEATINGINDEX="'+CAST(@id as varchar(MAX))+'"]/Compliance/EstPolicyCount[@REPEATINGTYPE="PropertyGroup"]''/rowdata[@REPEATINGINDEX="Total12"/text())[1]'', N''nvarchar(MAX)'') as [Total12]
FROM  (SELECT TransID, CAST(TransXML as XML) as TransXML FROM  [dbo].[DA_TRANSACTIONS]) t
CROSS APPLY TransXML.nodes(''pagedata/BinderSections[@REPEATINGTYPE="PageList"]'') as pagedata(BinderSection)
--CROSS APPLY BinderSection.nodes(''Compliance/EstPolicyCount[@REPEATINGTYPE="PropertyGroup"]'') as pagedata2(EstPolicyCount)
WHERE  t.TransID = ''B-2511''';

EXEC (@SQL)

SET @id = @id + 1
END
```

(I am not sure why its not turning into code for stackoverflow - i am new)

The part I am trying to get is this:

```
<EstPolicyCount REPEATINGTYPE="PropertyGroup">
<rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="Total12">30</rowdata>
<rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="NonSME">30</rowdata>
```

The output I would want is

| TransID | Total12 | TotalSME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B-2511 | 30 | 30 |

SQL version is Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2)

Thanks

Nick

Comment: Just a note I cut down the XML to make it easier / remove data which can be personal, so some of the SQL won't apply, its just the estpolicycount i need help

Comment: While asking a question you need to provide a **minimal reproducible example**:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT, T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic, and your attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Apologies will correct now

Comment: Where is your #1, i.e. **DDL and sample data population**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **minimal reproducible example** is not provided. So, I am shooting from the hip.

Please try the following solution.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @DA_TRANSACTIONS TABLE (TransID VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY, TransXML NVARCHAR(MAX));
INSERT INTO @DA_TRANSACTIONS (TransID, TransXML) VALUES
('B-2511', N'<pagedata>
  <BinderSections REPEATINGTYPE="PageList">
    <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="1">
       <Compliance>
        <EstPolicyCount REPEATINGTYPE="PropertyGroup">
          <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="Total12">30</rowdata>
          <rowdata REPEATINGINDEX="NonSME">30</rowdata>
        </EstPolicyCount>
      </Compliance>
    </rowdata>
  </BinderSections>
</pagedata>');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.TransID
    , Total12 = c.value('(rowdata[@REPEATINGINDEX="Total12"]/text())[1]', 'INT')
    , TotalSME = c.value('(rowdata[@REPEATINGINDEX="NonSME"]/text())[1]', 'INT')
FROM @DA_TRANSACTIONS AS t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TrXML = TRY_CAST(TransXML AS XML)) x
    CROSS APPLY TrXML.nodes('/pagedata/BinderSections/rowdata/Compliance/EstPolicyCount') AS t1(c);
```

**Output**

```
+---------+---------+----------+
| TransID | Total12 | TotalSME |
+---------+---------+----------+
| B-2511  |      30 |       30 |
+---------+---------+----------+
```

Comment: hi this worked perfectly!! many thanks and sorry I forgot the DDL

Comment: @NicholasCampbell, glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.

Comment: Apologies for delay Yitzhak, much appreciated for the help! :)